# How to position a div with background image within a div with background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Still new to Javascript and JQuery. I have a `div` with a `div`. I set a background image in the outer `div` and I want to set another image in the inner `div`. I also want to set the inner `div` at top left 10 10 from the outer `div`.

I am using the following code (`lc` is outter, `slc1` is inner):

```
$(myPage.hash('lc')).css("background-image", "url(images/leftcolumn640.jpg)");

$(myPage.hash('slc1')).width("200");
$(myPage.hash('slc1')).height("200");
$(myPage.hash('slc1')).position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "left top",
    offset: "10 10",
    of: myPage.hash('lc'),
    collision: "fit"
}); 

$(myPage.hash('slc1')).css("background-image", "url(images/Square_200w_200h.png)");
```

Both the inner and outer image are diplayed, but the inner image is not at 10 10 of the outer image. What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(myPage.hash('slc1')).css({
  width:200,
  height:200,
  position:"relative",
  top:10,
  left:10,
  backgroundImage:"url(images/Square_200w_200h.png)"
});
```

Alternatively, you could try using margins instead of positions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to this why not start with the basics before you move onto a framework like JQuery?

In HTML* and CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100;
    left: 100;
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    top: 10;
    left: 10;
    background-image: url('path/to/image1.jpg');
}
</style>

<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

Comment: They may still want JS to update/modify background images depending on events; but I think that having a solid basis of straight-up CSS is still very important. That's what it's there for! Use JS only to modify the things that are meant to be dynamic.

Comment: I agree; Besides for such a simple thing as this, isn't it just easier to write it in plain HTML/CSS? The difference being that Tim-berners Lee designed HTML to be easy to read where as JQuery was not.

Comment: Thing is, I am not 'that' new to JS. It is written all over the internet that one is better off using a framework like JQuery to tackle issues found across browsers, and position() is supposed to do the job, but it doesn't. Last, the code example I provide is only a small portion of all my JS, which is much more complex.